# Slack bot to show text as the bot

Tags: slack-api, slack

Looking for a simple bot that will just echo the text after the command as the bot user.

Example:

In a channel I type:

/botname Hello!

Then instead of me saying, "Hello!" the bot will say it instead.

botname
    Hello!

Quite simple, but I can't find anything out there that does this.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a particular part in this that you are struggling to do? This would be simple to do with any slack framework that supports slash commands, such as [botkit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit). In fact it might actually be even simpler without a framework.

All this would be doing is to respond to the request that Slack makes to your server as a result of the slash command invocation with the content of the `text` field:
[image]
(Image taken from https://api.slack.com/slash-commands)